# Compare dates of List of String with that of DataTable and update the DataTable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am working on a report project and I have a DataTable:

[image]

The dates are coming from database (PIVOTS).

I have a code which get me only weekly-off dates:

```
List<string> getWeekOffDates = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("WeekOff").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToList();
```

I want to compare that whether the **getWeekOffDates** and the dates in my DataTable matches (out of the entire month dates). If yes,then assign "WO" string to them which means **WeekOff**

For example:

The **getWeekOffDates** will have a list of dates, and 2020-01-04, 2020-01-05 are two of them. Now I want to check these dates in my datatable, if present then I would like to assign "WO" string to those dates in all rows to mention it is a week off.

I have tried this code, but doesn't seem that datatable gets updated.

```
public DataTable GetHolidays(DataSet ds, List<string> dates, DataTable dt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= dates.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        // checks if dates from WeekOffDays Column is present
        bool weekOff = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(x => dates.Contains(x.Field<DateTime>("WeekOffDays").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));

        // get the weekoff dates
        List<string> getWeekOffDates = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("WeekOff").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToArray();

        if (weekOff)
        {
            // string wo = dates[i].ToString();

            string offs = getWeekOffDates[i].ToString();

            dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(r => r.ColumnName == offs).FirstOrDefault().DefaultValue="WO";

        }

    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    return dt;
}
```

Then I am calling this function on a button click:

```
protected void btnGetLeaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    DataTable report= DataAccess.GetDataInDataTable(ConstantFieldsModel.PRIMARYCONNECTION, "usp_GetAnalystLeaveReport", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param);

    List<string> columnNames = report.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(16).Select(cols => cols.ColumnName).ToList();

    GetHolidays(GetData(), columnNames,report);
```

}

The DefaultValue assigned should update the DataTable but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: fire up the debugger and figure out what values you're getting for this line `            dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(r => r.ColumnName == offs).FirstOrDefault().DefaultValue="WO";
`

Comment: I am getting all the date columns of my datatable.

Comment: Could you try to iterate that list and apply defaultValue to the datatable again?

Comment: @sommmen, if I do that then using
 foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        dt.Columns[getWeekOffDates].DefaultValue = "WO";
                    }
It shows error saying cannot convert List<string> to int. If I convert it in list, it shows object reference error.